# Integrating IBM RAD with Websphere on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, websphere-7, websphere-portal

I don't have much hardware resources so I want to use RAD directly in cloud. Is it possible to develop portal applications directly on Amazon EC2 base Websphere instance by using IBM RAD IDE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean portlets as in JSR286 running on a WebSphere Portal Server - then I would say no.

The installation process of a WebSphere Portal is somewhat elaborate and I would not think, that you will manage to install the portal server on the Amazon Cloud. Even though the Portal is indeed a WebSphere Application.

Portal is kind of picky about its requirements - especially during the installation process.